# List of objects null when using LINQ Take and Skip methods with EFCore

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core version 3.1.6.

I have two classes like this:

```
public class Example{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public int ExampleGroupId {get;set;}
    public ExampleGroup ExampleGroup {get;set;}
}

public class ExampleGroup{
    public string ExampleGroupName {get;set;}
    
    public int ExampleGroupId {get;set;}
    public List<Example> Examples {get;set;}
}
```

When I do a `.ToList()` the results are fine:

```
var examples = _context.Examples.Include(e => e.ExampleGroup).ToList();

// ... ExampleGroup list has values
/*
{
    Id = 1, 
    Name = "example1",
    ExampleGroupId = 1,
    ExampleGroup = 
    {
        ExampleGroupName = "exampleGroup1"
    }   
}
*/
```

When I try doing `.Skip()` and `.Take()` methods, it returns `null` for the `ExampleGroup` List.

```
examples.Skip(1).Take(1).ToList();

/*
{
    Id = 1, 
    Name = "example1",
    ExampleGroupId = 1,
    ExampleGroup = null
}
*/
```

Why is the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` doing this?

Comment: are you using efcore or some other one? lookup lazy loading...

Comment: its not linq per se but the query provider.

Comment: Remove the Take and see what you get.

Comment: Is this `examples.Skip(1).Take(1).ToList();` right after `var examples = _context.Examples.Include(e => e.ExampleGroup).ToList();`? Or are you modifying `examples` somewhere in between?

Comment: Is this some version dependent weirdness? I can't reproduce it in EF Core 5.

Comment: @Leaky I think it may be a bug in EF Core 3.1.6 ?? I upgraded to EF Core 5 and it works

Comment: @ironman, it is definitely bug. If you can work with EF Core 5 - do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Data needs to have a unique key. I was having the same problem, using Moq to mock a method that would return first the 2 first data from a list, and then skip 2 and return 2, so I had this test list where the first 2 data had a unique property, the ID, and then the rest of the objects on that list were generic object(I have only instantiated them like new MyObject()) just to fill the list. When editing the third and fourth objects to have the ID at least(Maybe to act as a unique key) it worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).